# Selecting dynamically on a materialized view

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a strange request from a client to dynamically select on different materialized views.  The view name would be a parameter in a stored procedure.

Example where I_MATERIALIZED_VIEW_NAME is the parameter:

```
select * 
from I_MATERIALIZED_VIEW_NAME
```

Can this be done?  What would be the syntax?

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic SQL and return a ref cursor; [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4429746/266304) (there's no difference between a table and an MV in this context). How will the caller consume the results though? Or do all the MVs have the same structure?

Comment: All MVs have the same structure.  There would be a stored procedure that uses the MVs.

Comment: Theoretically, if they all have the same structure, you could create a view that UNION ALLs them, with an extra column containing a string literal for the MV name. Then you can select by supplying the string. This is known as a "partition view".